# Optaplanner msg: No doable selected move at step index (37318), time spent (526159). Terminating phase early

Tags: optaplanner

I have a variation of VRP with multiple day deliveries, and a "demand" which changes based on the date of the previous delivery. (Liquid product tanks)
The solution takes quite a while (a few hours) to "solve". 56 locations and about 10 deliveries per location. 3 origins and 6 months of possible delivery days.

I'm using Optplanner, version 8.29.0.Final, and have copied the config.xml from the VRP example.

My problem is that solving stops before a feasible solution is found with the message:

No doable selected move at step index (37318), time spent (526159). Terminating phase early.

When I restart solving, the score continues to improve.

What does that message mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable multithreaded solving (by uncommenting the `<moveThreadCount>AUTO</moveThreadCount>` line)? If so, you probably ran into https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2835 , a regression for multithreaded solving introduced in 8.29.0.Final that will be fixed in 8.30.0.Final.
You can fix the issue by upgrading to 8.30.0.Final when it releases.

Comment: I do have that enabled. Will try commenting it out and rerunning right now.